# Sorting HTML Table With TableSorter

Tags: php, jquery, html, tablesorter

I am attempting to add sortable columns to my html table and I thought I would give the jquery tablesorter a try.  This is my syntax sans the actual DB call, and I think I have it set-up properly, however my table is not allowing me to sort.  Why am I not able to sort?

```
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#SaleDistro").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 
</script>
</head>

<table id="SaleDistro" class="tablesorter" border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Sales Name </th>
<th>Sales Region </th>
<th>Sales Count </th>
<th>Sales Supervisor </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php
foreach ($query as $res) 
{
print "<tbody>";
print "<tr>";
print "<td>" . $res->sn . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $res->sr . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $res->sc . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $res->ss . "</td>";
print "</tr>";
print "</tbody>";
}
?>
</table>
</html>
```

EDIT --->
I edited my syntax to read like this, but still have the issue

```
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
foreach ($query as $res) 
{
print "<tr>";
print "<td>" . $res->sn . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $res->sr . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $res->sc . "</td>";
print "<td>" . $res->ss . "</td>";
print "</tr>";
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

**EDIT 2**
Below is update to show how `$query` get's it's value

```
    <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#SaleDistro").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 
</script>
</head>
<?php
    $option = array();
    $option['driver'] = 'mssql';
    $option['host'] = 'IP Address';
    $option['user'] = 'username';
    $option['password'] = 'password';
    $option['database'] = 'database';
    $option['prefix'] = '';
    $db = JDatabase::getInstance($option);
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query = "Select SalesName, SalesRegion, SalesCount, SalesSupervisor from salesdata;";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $query = $db->loadObjectList();
    if ($query) 
    {
?>
<table id="SaleDistro" class="tablesorter" border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Sales Name </th>
        <th>Sales Region </th>
        <th>Sales Count </th>
        <th>Sales Supervisor </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
<?php
foreach ($query as $res) 
{
    print "<tbody>";
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td>" . $res->sn . "</td>";
    print "<td>" . $res->sr . "</td>";
    print "<td>" . $res->sc . "</td>";
    print "<td>" . $res->ss . "</td>";
    print "</tr>";
    print "</tbody>";
}
?>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: It is as @spiral_generator said, if you want the table to sort, move the `print "<tbody>";` outside of the `foreach` loop. If you're using the original tablesorter, all "extra" tbodies are completely ignored. If using my [fork of tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) then the rows within each separate tbody are sorted independently.

Answer (score 1):

You only want one `<tbody>` opening and closing tag each, so you need to move them out of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: See my edit...I think I tried that and still no luck.

Comment: Just had a look at the tablesorter documentation. Did you actually include the two javascript plugins like this: `/path/to/jquery-latest.js` and `/path/to/jquery.tablesorter.js`? You need to replace those with proper file paths. Also you have no `<body>` tag in your HTML.

Comment: LOL - I changed that to actual paths, just left as such for my example above.  Hmm...let me add a body tag and see if that makes a diff.  Adding in a body tag made no diff

Comment: Seems to work fine for me though, as far as I can tell without more detail. Is the table displayed fine otherwise, and are you sure both plugin paths are correct?

Comment: Table is displayed okay, If I paste the path in my browser of where I have in my script I get the javascript page display on screen...so I believe it is pointed properly...

Comment: Then, unless someone else can help, you'll need to post your PHP.

Comment: Which part of my php do you need to see?  It is a massive file.

Comment: Where you get `$query` from.

Comment: Not immediately, but I'll have another look at it tomorrow. You'll want to look into seperating your server-side code (PHP / SQL) from your HTML / CSS / JS ( = client side code) at some point though to keep it all organized.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147682/discussion-between-spiral-generator-and-bellhopbydayametuercoderbynigh).